Using Axios with the default Laravel Boostrap file
In my JS I am doing:
import axios from 'axios';

Then i'm using axios in the usual fashion.
But i've also seen this in the bootstrap file that comes with Laravel:
import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


As I am importing axios again I presume that I am not using the bootstrap version of axios with the default headers config?

What is the purpose of this config?

If I want to use the bootstrap version of axios, instead of importing it to my file, should I do window.axios to make a axios call?


